# Is there a clear mathematical statement of what problem Hierarchical Risk Parity is solving?

Tags: risk, portfolio

Prado's paper is really just an algorithm for solving some inverse problem. Has anyone seen a clear statement of that inverse problem? Or do you know how to write it simply?

The first step is just a linkage matrix (see scipy.linkage) so that is pretty clear and can probably be posed as a constrained DAG optimization in some continuous formulation. The quasi-diag and recursive bisection are some sort of inversion operation. But what is the precise statement of that problem? Prado just comes up with an algorithm without context.

Is this solving some optimal allocation with dag structure?

Is there really no statement of what this is actually doing or have I missed a reference in my reading?